# Need Help using the Mod Function for looping in C#

Tags: c#, loops, modulo

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i = (i%10))
{
    age = (age +10);
    int_year = (int_year + 10);
```

So I am trying to use the Mod function for looping in C#, the requirement is that it the int_year and age loop 100 times but only every 10th increment is kept. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You aren't modifying `i` inside your loop (that you've shown), so this is an infinite loop. And what exactly do you mean by "only every 10th increment is kept"?

Comment: You also don't seem to be using `i` in your loop. Maybe if you could explain how you planned to use the value, we could help you more.

Comment: "Requirement"? ... you could just `i += 10` for your step..

Comment: I note that the % operator is not the modulus operator. It is the remainder operator.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just mod 10 within the loop to determine if this is the 10th iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 10 == 0)
    {
         // Every 10th iteration
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use step equal to 10:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 10)
{
      // Every 10th iteration
}
```

I think it's more efficient than using mod.